# Create a local variable in Haml only

Tags: haml

I'm using Haml as a quick way of prototyping layouts.  This is not using Rails, Sinatra or any framework.

What I want to do is declare a variable at the top and be able to call it throughout the page, similar to the way I can declare a variable in Sass and use it throughout the code.

```
!!! 5
  %body
    / Declare Variable
    - $type = 'Audio'

    .container{:id => "page-#{$type}"}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Prefixing a variable with `$` in ruby defines it as global, which is probably not what you want. Drop the `$` and just use `type`.

Comment: yeah, it was.  it was a completely foolish mistake on my part.  thank you guys.  and thanks for the heads up about the global variable as well.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Drop the `$` to avoid declaring a global variable. It should work just fine.

```
!!! 5
  %body
    / Declare Variable
    - type = 'Audio'
    .container{:id => "page-#{type}"}
```